# Error while running a php code in wamp server

Tags: php, wampserver, fatal-error

I'm a fresher to php and I want to run this code.

```
<?php
require_once("lib/streams.php");
require_once("lib/gettext.php");

$locale_lang = $_GET['lang'];
$locale_file = new fileReader ("locale/locale_lang/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo");
$locale_fetch = new gettext_reader($locale_file);

function _($text)
{
global $locale_fetch;
return $locale_fetch->translate($text);
}

?>
```

I got this code by referring a tutorial. But I'm getting an error, while running this on wamp server.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _() in C:\wamp\www\Localization\index.php on line 14
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: php already has a function _() so you are trying to overwrite it - thus the error

Comment: Thank you so much. But I got this code from a video tutorial and that code works well. How can I fix this?

Comment: I expect the function is already defined in `gettext.php`. You don't need to define it yourself.